# Can the Basic Free (not the OSS) docker image of elastic stack be used in the product development of a commercial organisation?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to setup elastic stack v7.2.0 for centralized logging, monitoring and alerting. This elastic stack setup will be part of a commercial organisation's product and all this will be sold to different customers.

I am confused whether I can use the Basic Free docker Image or I have the only option to go ahead only with the -OSS docker images? Refer [link](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions)

I referred few links but I did not find answers to my question. 
1. https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free
2. https://www.elastic.co/blog/doubling-down-on-open
3. https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/open
4. [is Security free in Elastic search Stack Features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201190/is-security-free-in-elastic-search-stack-features)
5. [Running Elastic without the Trial License](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079501/running-elastic-without-the-trial-license)

From the above links I know that some of the features are indefinitely free under the Elastic License https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/0d8aa7527e242fbda9d84867ab8bc955758eebce/licenses/ELASTIC-LICENSE.txt

But my question is can I use the Elastic license for building commercial products?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the license file, please contact elastic_license@elastic.co to discuss this — some limitations will apply to your use case.